# How to change the text of menubar in prestashop theme?

Tags: web, prestashop

**Hii,

Can someone  tell me how to edit the text of menubar  , cuz I try it to change in source code , but it was impossible because the html code its hidden in prestashop theme (they use tpl file).

So it is possible to change ??**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you tried to change it via the code. Revert all changes back and you can change the text of all front office and back office translations (including installed moudules) using the Translation Tool.

In 1.4 it is under Tools>Translations in 1.5 it is in Localization>Translations

You can then navigate to the correct translation, back office, front office, installed module etc. I hope this helps!

Comment: Yes I have translate the other modules , but when it comes to menu bar and categories in there ,  I can't find module where to change the name of categories in menubar ?

Comment: I found the solution , problem was at catalog tab , there was option to translate the menu bar . Anyway thanks for your help :)